How to see the solution of heat equation on whole line is uniformly Schwartz by the proof in Stein Fourier Analysis
This is the result proved in Stein Fourier Analysis Chapter 5, 5.2 Corollary 2.2.


Suppose $\Phi_{t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ 4\pi t }}\exp\left( -\frac{x^{2}}{4t} \right)$ is the heat kernal.
It said that if $$\begin{align*}
u(x,t) = (\Phi_{t} *f)(x)  
\end{align*}$$is the solution for the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}$ , then $u(\cdot,t) \in S(\mathbb{R})$ uniformly in $t$ where $S(\mathbb{R})$ is the Schwartz space.
I have 2 questions
1）” Uniformly in $t$ ". Does this mean that for any given $T>0$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
\sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R} , 0<t<T} |x|^{k} |\partial_{x}^{l}u|  \leq M_{k,l}<\infty
\end{align*}$$ That is, the bound $M_{k,l}$ doesn't depend on the $t$ choose in $(0,T)$
2）If my understanding is right. I'm wondering how the proof in the book showed the result.
In the book, it shows that $$\begin{align*}
|u(x,t)| \leq \frac{C_{N}}{(1+|x|)^{N}} +\frac{C}{\sqrt[]{ t }}e^{-cx^{2}/ t}
\end{align*}$$ I can show this inequality, but if I consider $$\begin{align*}
|x|^{k}|u(x,t)| \leq \frac{C_{N}|x|^{k}}{(1+|x|)^{N}} + \frac{C}{\sqrt[]{ t }}|x|^{k} e^{-c x^{2}/t}
\end{align*}$$ Then, for the first term, I can choose $N$ to be very large such that it is bounded by some constant. However, for the second term, I can't see why it can be bounded on for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in (0, T)$ with a constant that doesn't depend on $t$.
Since when $t\to 0$ , we indeed have $\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ t }}\to \infty$ . The function $\frac{C}{\sqrt[]{ t }}|x|^{k}e^{-cx^{2}/t}$ is a 2 variables function, and it's hard for me to discuss the limit of it.
Any help on this? Thanks.

For your second question, I think the point is that you can bound the integral by making the substitution $s = \sqrt{C/t}x$ which eliminates the square root on the exponent in the exponential and eliminates the $\sqrt{t}$ on the denominator. Then the argument in f will depend on t but you can still bound the integral since f rapidly decreasing.

I'm sorry, but I still can't clearly see why. Can you make this to be a solution to this question?

I think I was wrong, thinking about it, you may want to use that the exponential function is Schwarz, and hence, $|x|^{k}{\sqrt{C}/\sqrt{t}}e^{-cx^2/t}$ is uniformly bounded in $t$ since you can bound it uniformly in the argument.
As for the rest of the integrand, I think  you can bound the integral over the splitted domain $|y|>|x|/2$ using the support  (you have to be careful with the traslation of the support)of $f$.
